# Schedule a service to run as admin at startup

Tags: c#, .net, security, service, windows-services

**My question**

How do I programmatically schedule a service to run as admin at startup (and without needing to save the admin password somewhere)?

**Background**

I want to allow a user to execute some action which would generally need admin privileges, *without* needing elevated privileges - by running some process as admin *once*. As far as I know, and please correct me if I'm wrong, this can't be done directly by telling the computer - please allow this action to be done without admin. So I want this first-run-as-admin to schedule a service to run at startup as admin, and the normal app will then communicate with this service, having the service execute the "admin-action" for it.

Comment: In your services control panel you can set up the account to be used for each service.

Comment: @LaurentLequenne Thanks. But as I wrote: `How do I programmatically schedule a service...`.